# Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test with exogenous breaks

Tags: r, unit-root

I would need to do a Philips-Perron test in R, while controlling for an exogenous break.

I found the Philips-Perron test in the package tseries (PP.test), but can't find (contrary to the CADF test) how to extend this test to control for an exogenous break. I'm not a programming expert, is there a way to easily include this in this test in R?

I had a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127265/structural-break-unit-root-test) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56072/unit-root-test-specification-with-a-structural-break), but this only offers alternative approaches to my problem, where I would need a perron test for my article..

Comment: Could you give a reference for the PP test with an exogenous break?

Comment: Equation 4 on p.6

http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1488&amp;context=commpapers

Answer (score 1):

I think what your a looking for is a test like performed in Perron, P. (1989), “The great crash, the oil price shock, and the unit root hypothesis”,
Econometrica , 57, pp.1361-1401 allowing for one structural break. I know that it is implemented in Eviews but I do not know if there is some R package that performs this test. 
José